# Layout height getting as -2

Tags: android, custom-controls, layout-inflater

The below is the xml that iam inflating within my `customList`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/holder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <exp.viswanath.dropper.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#e1e1e1"
        android:padding="4dp" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/custom_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my custom view Layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<exp.viswanath.dropper.CustomList
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Iam getting the `height` of `Layout` with id `parent` and `listview` as -1 and -2 . But iam getting the correct height for element with id `custom_view` as 105. Iam inflating this within the constructor of my `CustomList`

**CODE**

```
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_dropper, null);

    parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.parent);

    Log.d("", "DEBUG:pl:" + parentLayout.getLayoutParams().height);

    myView = (CustomView)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
    _viewHeight = myView.getLayoutParams().height;

    initList();

    _height = (-1) * _viewHeight;
    Log.d("","height:" + _height);
    listView = (ListView)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Log.d("", "DEBUG:lv:" + listView.getLayoutParams().height);
```

Does any one knows the problem or experienced the same? The layout is not visible at all

**PROBLEM**

`MY VIEW IS NOT VISIBLE`

Comment: can you please post your java code?

Comment: Yeah, i just updated the code

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `myView.getLayoutParams().height;` will not return you the height as it has not been measured yet. In tghis case it returns you the constant associated with the view such as `FILL_PARENT`, `WRAP_CONTENT` etc. See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#height):

> Information about how tall the view wants to be. Can be one of the
>   constants FILL_PARENT (replaced by MATCH_PARENT , in API Level 8) or
>   WRAP_CONTENT. or an exact size.

To get the size of a layout, your should be using `getWidth()` or `getMeasuredWidth()` methods.  However, these methods won't give you a meaningful answer until the view has been measured. Read about [how android draws views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) here.

You can get the correct size, by overriding the `onWindowFocusChanged()` as [mentioned in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/nNEp6xBnPiw).

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
    myView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("", "DEBUG:lv:" + myView.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Actually i dont need the  height,Since the view is not visible , I just tried to get the height, Its not getting displayed and the height is -2

Comment: I have explained why you get -2. If you don't need the height then ignore the second part of my answer. It may help someone else who needs the height..

Comment: So , why my view is not displayed?

Comment: Ahh.. so this is your question.. the title is completely misleading.. anyway.. can you post your complete `getView()`

Comment: I dont have a get view method, Its a class extending View and within the constructor i have the code

Comment: you mean the custom view layout is not visible? It maybe because your `listView` is `fill_parent` so custom view is behind that.. you cant see it.. can you verify this by hiding the listview and then checking if you can see it..

Comment: No iam getting a blank screen(White).theres nothing in there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42776/discussion-between-amulya-khare-and-arju)

Comment: Got it, Thanks for your help ,, It was missing addView() was missing, I thought that inflater will add that implicitly but that was wrong

Comment: haha! if you look at the discussion.. thats exactly what i mentioned. glad it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
listView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.d("", "DEBUG:lv:" + listView.getLayoutParams().height);
            }
        });
```

Comment: still iam getting the same